# How can I align all my equations to the left?

Tags: align

This is my code but I want it to align to the left, more like the second part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \sum F_x = 0 \\
    F_{Ax}+F_{AF}+F_{BF}\cos(30)= 0
    \\ 
    \\
    \sum F_y = 0 \\ 
    F_{Ay}+F_{BF}\sin(30) = 0
\end{gather*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to `TeX.SE`... As you are not providing full `MWE`, I assumed that you are using one of a `LaTeX` standard class file `book`, here is the modified `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \sum F_x = 0 \\
    F_{Ax}+F_{AF}+F_{BF}\cos(30)= 0
    \\ 
    \\
    \sum F_y = 0 \\ 
    F_{Ay}+F_{BF}\sin(30) = 0
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```